# Assigning variable with jQuery problem

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to use jQuery to combine the user's select field choices (category + contributors) and insert this into a hidden field with an id of as_q, but when I run the script the value of as_q is always empty.

At the moment, I call the function when the user clicks submit - it gets the value of the two select fields and combines them, before assigning them to the as_q field - at least that's my logic.

Perhaps I've got the  in the wrong place? My current code is below. Any help greatly appreciated, thanks

```
<form action="<? echo $PHP_SELF;?>" method="get" id="cse-search-box">
  <input type="text" name="q" size="31"/>
  <select name="category">
    <option>Movies</option>
    <option>Film</option>
    <option>Fashion</option>
  </select>
  <select name="contributors">
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
    <option>Three</option>
  </select>
  <input type="hidden" name="as_q" id="as_q" value="" />
  <input type="submit" name="sa" value="Search" id="submit_query" />
</form>

<script>      
  $('#submit_query').click(function (){
    var category = $('[name=category]').val();
    var contributors = $('[name=contributors]').val();

    $('[#as_q]').val(category+' '+contributors);

  }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Putting your code into a test page results in it working fine in FF3.5. Can you provide any more details?

Comment: I've tried a test page myself outside of the deployment server, and that doesn't work work correctly either - I'm looking at the as_q section in the url, which is empty. 

Can I ask how you're testing that the two fields have been combined into as_q? Maybe that'll help me to provide some more accurate info?

Comment: I really recommend using pastehtml.com for questions like this. http://pastehtml.com/view/090921UbqT7OfJ.html

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess - get rid of the square brackets from...

```
$('[#as_q]').val(category+' '+contributors);
```

Comment: I realised this after submitting the question, but it's not the problem, thanks

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other suggestions made:

1 - Put your code into a `$(document).ready(...` block. This could be why it's not working.

2 - Give your selects IDs for better performance, [attribute filters](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors) (like [name=blah]) are not the snappiest way to select elements.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit_query').click(function (){
        var category = $('#category').val();
        var contributors = $('#contributors').val();
        $('#as_q').val(category + ' ' + contributors);
    });  
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'm using ID selectors now.

I've wrapped the code into the doc ready block, but still no luck - really confused as to why this isn't working!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the test code I'm using that results in your code working fine for me.

The file is called sandbox.php (I mention this as the only thing that's really unknown is if you've given your file a .php extension)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<!-- Above Doctype should provide S mode in Moz, Safari, Opera, IE8 and A (almost standards) in IE6/7 -->
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/text+html;utf-8">

  <title>Sandbox</title>
  <link type="text/css" href="http://jqueryui.com/latest/themes/base/ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryui.com/latest/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/tags/ui/latest/ui/effects.core.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit_query').click(function (){
    var category = $('[name=category]').val();
    var contributors = $('[name=contributors]').val();

    $('#as_q').val(category+' '+contributors);
  }); 
    });

</script>
</head>
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['as_q'])) {
    echo $_REQUEST['as_q'];
}
?>
<body class="calendarPage">
<form action="#" method="get" id="cse-search-box">
  <input type="text" name="q" size="31"/>
  <select name="category">
    <option>Movies</option>
    <option>Film</option>
    <option>Fashion</option>
  </select>
  <select name="contributors">
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
    <option>Three</option>
  </select>
  <input type="hidden" name="as_q" id="as_q" value="" />
  <input type="submit" name="sa" value="Search" id="submit_query" />
</form>


    </body>


</html>
```

Comment: Right, thanks - using your code on the development server, everything works fine. As far as I can tell, the only difference between my code and yours is the version of jQuery that's being used on the site I'm developing for - 1.2.6. 
I don't know the differences between the versions, but I wouldn't have thought this was the problem? Unless the included jquery, which is stored on the server locally, has been edited? I'm going to investigate and try to get some more info!

Answer (score 0):

Don't put square brackets around "as_q". Also, don't do this on the click of the submit button. That won't capture all the ways a form can be submitted. Instead do it on the form submit event:

```
$("#cse-search-box").submit(function() {
  var category = $('[name=category]').val();
  var contributors = $('[name=contributors]').val();
  $('#as_q').val(category+' '+contributors);
});
```

**Note:** calling form.submit() will bypass this handler too (on some browsers) but that'll bypass your click() event anyway.

Comment: I was doing it this way originally, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Both ways leave as_q empty...I'm not an expert by any means so at a loss here! Any further help appreciated.